# React MUI V5 Creating a shared library - what CSS way should i choose?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, shared-libraries

I'm working on creating a shared library in react and I'm pretty new to React language and a little confused about the Material Ui package for React.

Currently I have an Angular based shared library using Material UI and I want to create the same type of library in React.
In Angular we take the components from the Material UI and change their CSS styles or create new components based on those Material UI components

Looking on MUI site I noticed there are a few option and I'm a little confused about which one should I use (or should I use a few of them together?)

- Regular CSS
- Styled Components
- CSS Modules
- Emotion
- Theme

What i would wish:

- A library that i can customize pretty easily - change font / spacing / colors / adding icons etc..
- Work with storybook in order to show the components
- Try not to use !important tag at all if possible
- Bundle size - small
- My project uses type script

Am I missing another option maybe?

If not, Which one of this options works the best with MUI V5 for a shared library which will just be export of different custom components based on MUI